# Dynamic includes in Jekyll with Liquid

Tags: ruby, dynamic, include, jekyll, liquid

I'm building my second Jekyll site and I'm trying to make the page layout pull in different includes based on variables.

For example, in `download.md`:

```
layout: page  
form: "free"  
sidebar: "terms"
```

With this, the site will no longer compile. It says

> Liquid error (line 17): wrong number of arguments (4 for 3).

Line 17 is the first if statement in the example below.

How should I set up these includes?

```
<article class="s-article t-twocol__article">
  <header class="s-article__header">
    <h1 class="s-article__title">{{ page.title }}</h1>
    <h4 class="s-article__lede">{{ page.lede }}</h4>
  </header>
  <div class="s-article__content">
    {% if {{page.form}} == "full" %}
      {% include c-form--full.html %}
    {% endif %}
    {% if {{page.form}} == "free" %}
      {% include c-form--free.html %}
    {% endif %}
    {{ content }}
  </div>
</article>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not looking at the right place.
"Line 17" is from some liquid parsing point of view and not related to your code line numbering.

The real problem is that you try to use `limit: n` on the `where` filter which is not valid.
The `limit: n` (as well as `offset: n`) can only be used on `for in` loop.

**_layout/page.html - line 47**

```
{% assign cards = site.posts | where:"type","premium" limit:1 %}
  {% for card in cards %}
    ..
```

Must be changed to :

```
{% assign cards = site.posts | where:"type","premium" %}
  {% for card in cards limit:1 %}
    ..
```

And you have three more occurrences in **index.html** at lines 21, 25 and 43, where you can move the `limit: n` from the `where` filter to the `for` loop.

Comment: That fixed it! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
{% if {{page.form}} == "free" %}
{% if {{page.form}} == "full" %}
```

To:

```
{% if page.form == "free" %}
{% if page.form == "full" %}
```

Comment: Can I see your code? Is it on github? I get a successful build apart from the missing include. What does your jekyll serve/terminal say?

Comment: https://github.com/energy7/datastore/ — but I didn't push to the gh-pages branch since it's busted